# Why doesn't JSUtility like document.querySelector Anymore?

Tags: javascript

I've tried using my old script which was flawless but now it won't format?!?!

```
// the snipped inside my major code that won't format:
document.querySelector(".chat-column-title:not(#chat-subrooms-toggle)").innerHTML = "Global Chat";
```

the site i use to format my code: http://jsutility.pjoneil.net

the error `http://prntscr.com/3icvwv`

here for you paranoid people :)

> Errors
>
> Line 118 character 9: Expected ':' and instead saw '.'.
>
> ...document.querySelector(".chat-column-title:not(#chat-subrooms-toggle)").in...
>
> Line 118 character 9: Expected an identifier and instead saw '.'.
>
> ...document.querySelector(".chat-column-title:not(#chat-subrooms-toggle)").in...
>
> Line 118 character 98: Expected '}' and instead saw ';'.
>
> ....chat-column-title:not(#chat-subrooms-toggle)").innerHTML = "Global Chat";..

Comment: It gave you an url as the error? Please post the error itself in your question (you can [edit] it), not links to some obscure sites.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in a third party resource.

Comment: nope if you open the link it will show the error lol sorry for not stating that (screenshot link)

Comment: how is it off topic i'm simply asking if javascript have somewhat altered the output for that.

Comment: Screenshot link? Even worse. Please post the text of the error you got.

Comment: wow you lot are so paranoid lol ok ill post it.

Comment: There are no syntax errors in your snippet. We cannot help you with issues you experience on another website, contact the author of the website instead.

Comment: @Stijn thats all i was asking... thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As the error clearly shows, you have an object literal immediately before that line of code, and you forgot the `}` to close it.

Proof:

- The `document` is not unexpected.
- The `.`, however, is. It was expecting a `:`
- The second error can be ignored as a direct consequence of the first error
- The final error shows that `;` is unexpected, as a `}` is missing.

The only time `}` is "expected" is when there are unmatched brackets, or when you fail to close an object literal. Since it's not the end of your code, it's an unfinished object literal. QED (Quite Enough Debugging)